# How to turn on my computer through python?

Tags: python

I am using ubuntu10.04.I am trying to turn on my system at particular date automatically.Is there any chance to turn on my computer through python code?

Comment: You do realize that if the computer isn't on, it can't execute any program, regardless of language?

Answer (score 12):

When your computer is turned off python is not able to run. You could start it from another computer via wake on lan http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_On_LAN

On Linux Systems you could do something like:

```
    os.system('sudo sh -c "echo date \'+%s\' -d \'+ 24 hours\' > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"')
```

This uses ACPI Wakeup for which some good information is provided here(it is in fact documentation for mythtv but is also usable for Linux in general):
http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup

Comment: how to declare this command in python code.sudo sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 24 hours'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" this is the .sh code for trun on the computer

Comment: This is possible via `os.system`, I edited my answer to include it. However this is (obviously only possible on linux systems)

Comment: thanks, but i need to give the date as manually instead of system date. How can i give?

Comment: @Viswa Then you should build the string inside the os.system() call by code and change it so it  matches your requirement. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings